# JavaScript adding number variables together within different functions

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In JavaScript I want to add two numeric variables: `film_cost` and `delivery_cost` and have them appear in a alert box.  These variables are within two different functions.

```
function getcost()
{
    var cost = document.getElementsByName("format");
    var len = cost.length

    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(cost[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = '£'+cost[i].value;
            var film_cost = cost[i].value;
        }
    }
}

function add_delivery()
{
    var delivery_cost = document.getElementsByName("delivery");
    var len = delivery_cost.length

    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(delivery_cost[i].checked)
        {
            var dvd_delivery = delivery_cost[i].value;
            var total = dvd_delivery+film_cost;
            alert(total);   
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
Delivery
<input type="radio" name="delivery"  
  onClick="add_delivery();" value="3.20">First Class<br/>
<input type="radio" name="delivery"  
  onClick="add_delivery();" value="4.20">Express Delivery<br/>
```

Film type:

```
<input type="radio" name="format" value="20" 
  onClick="getcost();">Blu-ray + UV Copy<br/>
<input type="radio" name="format" value="14.50"
  onClick="getcost();">DVD + UV Copy<br/>
<input type="radio" name="format" value="30" 
  onClick="getcost();">Limited Edition DVD + UV Copy<br/>
<input type="radio" name="format" value="13" 
  onClick="getcost();">Download<br/>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: There are a few problems here, but the root problem is that `film_cost` is only defined within  `get_cost()`

Do you want to use multiple costs? It looks like `format` is a set of checkboxes in your html... if so, do you want to sum the film costs or just use the first one?

Comment: Format is a set of radio buttons as is delivery I would like the selected values to add together to create one total with both the film picked and the delivery.

Comment: in that case, an optimization that could be made would be to select the radio button directly, rather than looping through all of them, by using a pseudo-selector instead of using `getElementsByName`. try `document.querySelector('input[name=format][checked]')` to get just the checked element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to gain access to the film_cost variable in the add_delivery() function.

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
function getcost()
{
    var cost = document.getElementsByName("format");
    var len = cost.length;
    var film_cost = 0;

    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(cost[i].checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = '£'+cost[i].value;
            film_cost = parseFloat(cost[i].value);
        }
    }
    return film_cost;
}

function add_delivery()
{
    var delivery_cost = document.getElementsByName("delivery");
    var len = delivery_cost.length;

    for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(delivery_cost[i].checked)
        {
            var dvd_delivery = parseFloat(delivery_cost[i].value);
            var total = dvd_delivery + getcost();
            alert(total);   
        }
    }
}
```

In this solution, the variable film_cost would default to 0, but will change if a box is checked.  `add_delivery()` calls `getcost()` so the variables `dvd_delivery` and `film_cost` will add together into the variable `total`.

It would be helpful if we could see the html, but I think this will help you.

One final recommendation would be to normalize the way you name your functions. It would help you (and others) read your code if you named them:

- `getCost()` and `addDelivery()`

or

- `get_cost()` and `add_delivery()`

**EDIT:** Added `parseFloat()` to turn `film_cost` and `dvd_delivery` into floats so they can add together in the alert.

Comment: Thank you that worked the variable is now appearing in the alert box however they don't add up but join together. I have added the HTML now.

Comment: Good call! Check my edit. You need to call `parseFloat()` with the `.value`s inside since `delivery_cost[i].value` is a string!

Comment: I did think it  was something to do with the data type all sorted now thanks :) I well be sure to rename my functions like you recommended.

Comment: No problemo! And good call, it's a good habit to get into. :)

Answer (score 0):

**film_cost** is not defined in the second function.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable film_cost is only inside the first function; therefore, when invoking the second function film_cost already "died".

An even simpler fix to the problem is simply:

```
var film_cost;

function getcost()
{
var cost = document.getElementsByName("format");
var len = cost.length

for (i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    if(cost[i].checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = '£'+cost[i].value;
        film_cost = cost[i].value;
    }
}
}

function add_delivery()
{
var delivery_cost = document.getElementsByName("delivery");
var len = delivery_cost.length

for (i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    if(delivery_cost[i].checked)
    {
        var dvd_delivery = delivery_cost[i].value;
        var total = dvd_delivery+film_cost;
        alert(total);   
    }
}
}
```

I only changed the first line, and the if(cost[i].checked) body.

### Hopefully it works as you'd hope!